# Lisp: EVAL/APPLY: Too few arguments (1 instead of at least 2)

Tags: common-lisp

Does anyone knows why I'm getting this error?

> EVAL/APPLY: Too few arguments (1 instead of at least 2) given to SUMTAIL .

```
(defun sum (n)
(sumTail 0 n)
)
(defun sumTail(r n)
(if (null n)
r
(sumTail (+ (first n) r) (rest n) )
)
)

(sumtail '(59 21 6 5 30 98 17 22 1 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's rewrite the functions so we can read them better:

```
(defun sumTail (r n) 
  (if (null n) 
      r 
      (sumTail (+ (first n) r) (rest n))))

(defun sum (n) 
  (sumTail 0 n))
```

Now, it is easy to see the reason of the error: you call `sumtail` with a single argument:

```
(sumTail '(59 21 6 5 30 98 17 22 1 0))
```

while it has been defined as requiring two arguments, to be bound to the parameters `r` and `n`.

But we can see that `sum` requires only an argument, and it calls correctly `sumtail` with `0` and the list.

So, when you have just an argument, you should call `sum`:

```
CL-USER> (sum '(59 21 6 5 30 98 17 22 1 0))
259
```

Note that `sumTail` is equivalent to `sumtail`, since in Common Lisp, unless you modify the reader, both symbols are read as `SUMTAIL`.

Finally, you can use just a single function if you exchange the arguments:

```
(defun sumtail (n &optional (r 0)) 
  (if (null n) 
      r 
      (sumTail (rest n) (+ (first n) r))))

CL-USER>  (sumtail '(59 21 6 5 30 98 17 22 1 0))
259
```

This is because we have defined the second argument as optional, with an initial value of `0` when not provided.